# ¿Cómo sumar las columnas seleccionadas en un Datagridview en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un DataGridView que se llena desde una base de datos; Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para sumar las filas seleccionadas de una columna.

Por ejemplo si tuviese el siguiente DataGridView:

```
id_venta        fechaVenta    Total 
  1             01-01-2019    2500
  2             02-01-2019    3500
  3             03-01-2019    2760
  4             04-01-2019    7500
  5             05-01-2019    9500
```

Y quisiese solamente sumar los valores que yo seleccione de la columna **total**.

Comment: Hola, Manuel. Hay metodos o codigos que ha probado para conseguir lo que quiere? Por favor agregalo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Y quisiese solamente sumar los valores que yo seleccione de la columna total.

Puedes hacer uso de la propiedad [MultiSelect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8). De este modo, el usuario podrá seleccionar más de una celda, de una respectiva columna (recalco que esta propiedad también sirve para seleccionar filas y columnas).

Otra propiedad que se necesitaría usar, es [SelectedCells](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells?view=netframework-4.8), dado que permitará saber la colección de celdas seleccionadas por el usuario.

El algoritmo para seleccionar únicamente celdas de la columna `Total` sería:

- Obtener la longitud de celdas seleccionadas por el usuario (esto se logra con [GetCellCount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcellcount?view=netframework-4.8))
- Ejecutar un bucle para recorrer cada posición de la colección de objetos (de SelectedCells).
- En cada iteración, se debe detectar si la celda pertenece a la columna `Total`.
- Por último, se usa la Propiedad [FormattedValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue?view=netframework-4.8) para poder obtener el valor actual de esa celda y se la debe convertir en tipo `Integer`.

El código en C# quedaría de esta forma:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cellSelected;
            int tot = 0;
            int value;
            //Obtenemos la cantidad de celdas seleccionadas por el usuario.
            cellSelected = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
            for (int i = 0; i != cellSelected; ++i)
            {
                //Detectamos si la celda seleccionada pertenece a la columna Total.
                if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex != 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Solo puedes seleccionar celdas de la columna Total.");
                    return;
                }
                //Obtenemos el valor actual de esa celda y la convertimos en tipo integer. 
                value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].FormattedValue);
                //Realizamos la suma respectiva.
                tot += value;
            }
            //Mostramos el total.
            MessageBox.Show("Total: " + tot);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la perfecta explicación. Quise poner a funcionar el codigo pero recibo el siguiente error =  **System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'**. Trate de cambiar el tipo de *tot* y de *value* a **double**, pero el error persiste. Alguna idea de como sulucionarlo?  **Edito:**  No habia realizado la conversión a **double**. Ya quedo funcionando perfecto. Muchas gracias!